# What does iOS's "missing character" replacement look like?

Tags: ios, unicode, fonts

If you have a Unicode character in a webpage that misses all the fonts, it gets rendered as a replacement character. (Although typically not **the** replacement character � aka U+FFFD, since that's reserved for invalid data.)

On Windows, this appears as a box, similar to □, U+25A1. On Android it's a crossed-out box in some fonts, similar to ☒, U+2612. What does it look like on iOS? I don't have an iPhone, so an image would be appreciated.

For reference: This will probably render as what I'm talking about, since it's in the private use area:

## 

Edit: This glyph is known as .notdef, and knowing that I was able to find a fascinatingly detailed account of font fallbacks and rendering here: https://www.figma.com/blog/when-fonts-fall/. In particular, it let me know that .notdef (also known as "tofu") is chosen from the **first** font in the chain and not the last, like I'd thought.

I'd still like to know how this appears on iOS, for compatibility reasons. I've seen some reports of plain box, others of box-with-question-mark. If it's primarily one, but sometimes the other (based on font or version), that is useful info.

Comment: It's  [Shape of .notdef glyph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/otspec170/recom#shape-of-notdef-glyph) and [defined by a _font_](http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/FFFD.html) rather than by a particular OS…

Comment: Looks like an empty box on my iPhone but what does that prove and what does it really matter?

Comment: Yes, what I'm talking about is the .notdef glyph and it is per-font. However, iOS has a particular set of system fonts, just as Windows, Android, etc. do. So in the normal font rendering chain on a webpage, once a glyph has missed all the "fancy" fonts you may have specified in CSS, it's going to show .notdef in the standard (usually sans-serif) system font.

I want to know what that looks like on iOS, for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Well I told you what I see in mobile Safari

Comment: @matt Yes but comments can't be accepted as answers :)